The value is of incorrect type[enter image description here GCP LOGGING QUERY Console
How can we convert a SQL conditional (i.e. WHERE clause) to be used in the UI console of GCP Logging Explorer?
As in:
timestamp >= "TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)"

enter image description here
However, with or without quotes, it returns an error message:
The value "timestamp >= "TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)" is of incorrect type[enter image description here][1]


In attempt to understand the correct format, which GCP logging console accepts, I compared these two lines of code
1. timestamp<="2024-07-18T18:12:00Z"
2. timestamp<="FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', '2024-07-18T18:12:00Z', 'UTC')"

Why does 1 work, and 2 doesn't?

timestamp>="2024-07-20T17:28:03Z"
timestamp>="FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())"
Surprisingly the first command line (i.e. static timestamp assignment) works fine on GCP Logging console, while the second (i.e. dynamic timestamp assignment) does not work. It's shows an error message: This value is of incorrect type. What is the different between them.
